# Google Cloud PHP Natural Language find date within sentence

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I am using the [Google Cloud PHP Natural Language](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/language) library, but I am struggling to extract the date from a sentence. The date would be in various formats e.g.

- Tomorrow at 9am
- Monday 23rd of July
- 01-01-2018
- 24-01-2018
- 01-24-2018 (if you're not British)

  I can get this working with Dialofglow, so it knows when an entity is a date and/or datetime, but for some reason with this library it cannot figure out if something is a date and/or date time

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can get dates out from text on Dialogflow because this is a Natural Language Understanding service, while Cloud NL API is only a Natural Language Processing service.

This means that on Cloud NL API you can only do some types of analyses, such as Syntax Analysis, Entity Analysis, Sentiment Analysis, Entity Sentiment Analysis and Content Classification.

You may say: "Wait, then why a date is not classified as an entity?" and the answer is that it could, but it's not a feature yet released on this product. You may consider to [request this feature on GCP's Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187079&template=1161362).